# $A^\prime$(the set of limit points of $A$) is connected.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that every singleton in X is a closed set. A is a connected subset of X. Then  $A^\prime$(the set of limit points of $A$) is connected.

I can't use the conditions in the question well. I know we should use contradiction but I fail to prove it.I know in the $T_{1}$ space, $A^\prime$ is clsoed.And in if $A$ is connected then $A$ added some limit points is also connected. But they didn't work.So how to prove this, can someone give me some hints?

Comment: What exactly is the set of single points? For those unfamiliar with the terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the closure of $A$ is always connected. This happened because if $\phi: cl(A)\to \{0,1\}$ is a continuous map, then it is continuous on $A$, that is connected, and so it is constant on $A$ (for example, its value is $0$). By contradiction, if there exists $x\in cl(A)\setminus A$ such that $\phi(x)=1$, then $x\in \phi^{-1}(1)$, i.e. $\phi^{-1}(1)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$. This means there exists $y\in A\cap \phi^{-1}(1)$ and so $\phi(y)=1$ that is a contradiction.

Now we can prove $A'$ is connected observing that $cl(A)=A'\cup I(A)$, where $I(A)$ is the set of isolated points of $A$. In our case $A$ has not isolated points because $A$ is connected. This means

$A'=cl(A)$ is connected.

Remark: You’re need the $T_1$ condition when you say $A$ has not isolated points. In fact if there exists an isolated point $x$, then there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $U\cap A=\{x\}$, i.e $\{x\}$ is an open and closed subset of $A$. This is a contradiction because $A$ is connected.

Comment: Isn't the set of limit points of $(0, 1)$ the whole interval $[0, 1]$?

Comment: I guess definitions might vary.  The definition I've seen (in Munkres, for instance) is that a point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if $x \in \overline{A \setminus \{x\}}$.

Comment: Now I corrected the argument according to wiki definition of limit point

Comment: @FedericoFallucca You used $T_1$ to deduce that $A$ connected implies $A$ has no isolated points.  This is not true without $T_1$.  Also the argument is only valid in the case that $A$ does not consist of a single point, so you should treat that case separately (in that case $T_1$ implies $A'=\emptyset$, so is connected trivially).

Comment: @tkf Thank you very much, I corrected it

Comment: If $\{x\}$ is a non-empty open closed subset of a connected space $A$, then $A=\{x\}$ (you do not have a contradiction).  Your statement that $A$ has no isolated points is still technically wrong - it should be: either $A$ has no isolated points or $A=\{x\}$.  You have dealt with the former case. In the latter case you can use the $T_1$ condition again to deduce $\bar A=\{x\}$ so $A'=\emptyset$.